# Checking variable A is determined. (DeterminedQ ?)

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

How can we (loosely) check whether variable `A` is determined, not directly computing `A`?
(= How can we define `DeterminedQ` function ?)

For example,

```
In[1] x=a+b
In[2] a=2
```

Then x is not completely determined yet. So,

```
In[3] DeterminedQ[x]
Out[3] False
```

But if we go further

```
In[4] b=2
```

then

```
Out[5] DeterminedQ[x]
Out[5] True
```

Because now `x=4`.

I have an idea. My idea is inspecting `Definition[x]`, and get variable names `v1,v2,...` those constructing `x`. Then inspect `Definition[v1], Definition[v2], ...`, repeat, repeat.
If we encounter a variable w such that defition[w] produces Null, then `x` is not determined, `DeterminedQ[x]` must be false.
Otherwise, variables at bottom level will turn out to be mixture of determined numbers or strings, etc. In this case `DeterminedQ[x]` must be true.

But there is a problem in my idea. For example,

```
b=Sqrt[3+2Sqrt[2]]
x=a*(b-1-Sqrt[2])
```

Then `x` is mathematically determined becuase `x == a*0 == 0`, but according to my idea,  `DeterminedQ[x]` becomes false, because `Definition[a]` becomes `Null`.

And if we make a mathematica code,

```
x = the least even number that is not sum of two prime numbers
```

(The code can be written using `NestWhile` command)
Then the existence of `x` is not known mathematically, but according to my idea, `DeterminedQ[x]` becomes true.

I don't care whether `x` is determined mathematically or not.
I just want `DeterminedQ` function, which is loose but super fast, always give true or false.

...Or, there may be a built-in function already. Can you construct/know
`DeterminedQ`-like function ?

Comment: Will `NumericQ` do what you want?

Comment: No the list {1,2,3} is determined but NumericQ gives us false. Matrix of determined numbers or determined strings are also determined, I think.

Comment: What do you need this functionality for?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your definitions of "determined." Do you mean `A` it would give a numeric value if it were evaluated?  If so, note that `NumericQ[A]` computes `A` and sees if the result is numeric. That seems not to be what is required by "determined, not directly computing A."

Comment: Logically... the first thing to do is, constructing a single 'logical statement' for x according to the definition of x (according to what I've done in .nb file so far). If there is no free variable in 'the logical statement', then it can be said x is determined. In this manner, you do not need any computation, just inspecting the structure of the logical statement is enough.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
DeterminedQ[x_List] := And @@ DeterminedQ /@ x;
DeterminedQ[x_] := NumericQ[x];
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a very clever code and perfectly works for list of list of list of... numbers.
But it computes x. So, it will take so long time to the output of
DeterminedQ[NestWhile[# + 1 &, 0, # < 10^100 &]]

Comment: My idea will work for such example.