# IntegerQ[x] gives false. Just leave it as it is

Tags: functions, function-construction, expression-test

Since `x` is an alphabet not an integer,

```
Clear[x];IntegerQ[x]
```

gives

```
False
```

But sometimes I want to leave it as it is

I want to construct function `IntegerQ2` :

```
Clear[x];{IntegerQ2[22],IntegerQ2[4.915],IntegerQ2[x]}
```

would give

```
{True,False,IntegerQ2[x]}
```

Can you help me? This problem is not just confined to `IntegerQ`. It applies to almost every predicate function.

Comment: small note: the kind of thing `x` is is a `Symbol`, not an alphabet! (just to help you search documentation) :)

Comment: Predicate functions are supposed to behave that way (maybe you knew this but stating it in case not).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ClearAll[IntegerQ2]
IntegerQ2[x_?NumericQ] := IntegerQ[x]

IntegerQ2 /@ {2, 4.95, x}
```

> ```
> {True, False, IntegerQ2[x]}
> ```

Comment: Thank you! General solution for BlahblahQ is related to my another question. Constructing DeterminedQ : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242142/checking-variable-a-is-determined-determinedq?rq=1

Comment: I think replacing NumericQ with DeterminedQ would improve the code. Note that the question with URL in the comment is not perfectly solved.